# Find values set on strings in source code C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So i have code in C# and in many locations I have set string values such as

```
BadRequest("Invalid ID") OR return "Hello"
```

I need all such values for review purposes. Is there any tool or utility that can simply output this list in Visual Studio or otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using Visual Studio find and replace?

Answer (score 0):

Search using Regular Expressions. Maybe something like :
BadRequest("Invalid ID")|return "Hello"

And filter the Look at file types to : *.cs in case you're sure its only in c# cs classes.

Comment: So I am looking for all instances of anything between double quotes that I added.